# Convertir fecha a mes-día-año

Tags: php

Hola buenos días estoy intentando cambiar el formato de una fecha la cual estoy obteniendo de una base de datos con el siguiente formato:

***23:26:39.000 GMT Mon Mar 9 2020***

La manera que necesito la fecha es de la siguiente forma:

***10-28-19 mes-día-año***

Les comparto mi código que tengo hasta ahora y lo que he obtenido.

```js
$fecha_inicio = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['connect_time']->me[string];
 $fecha_inicio1 = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($fecha_inicio));
 echo("------------------".$fecha_inicio1."-----------");
```

> Resultado que obtengo

***03-08-2020***

Mi duda es porque me pone 08 cuando debería ser 09.

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe al `date_default_timezone_set()` que tienes en tu servidor. No es lo mismo que yo tenga:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$fecha_inicio = '23:26:39.000 GMT Mon Mar 9 2020';
$fecha_fin    = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($fecha_inicio));
echo $fecha_fin; // Imprime: 03-08-2020
```

A esto:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
$fecha_inicio = '23:26:39.000 GMT Mon Mar 9 2020';
$fecha_fin    = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($fecha_inicio));
echo $fecha_fin; // Imprime: 03-09-2020
```

Estas haciendo uso de **GMT** (Greenwich Mean Time), si lo quitas y lo dejas como `"23:26:39.000 Mon Mar 9 2020"` te dará la hora correcta acorde al timezone de tu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá deberías usar `DateTime`

```
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'H:i:s ??? D M j Y',
    '23:26:39 GMT Mon Mar 9 2020' );
echo date_format( $fecha, 'Y-m-d' );
```